# what is the IDXGIFactory1::IsCurrent work for?

Tags: directx, directx-11, dxgi

I notices that IDXGIFactory1 only add two interface from IDXGIFactory, which are EnumAdapter1 and IsCurrent.

1.So, what is the use of IsCurrent？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IsCurrent` method is for dealing with cases where information about the outputs that is cached internally by DXGI is outdated, meaning you should create a new factory.

This comes up in the handling of HDR10 displays. You can see it's use in my implementation of [DeviceResources](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DeviceResources) for [DX11](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp) and [DX12](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d12game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp)

Comment: i found a new Feature "improved support for remote desktops" of  DXGI1.1 in your paper "DirectX 11 Technology Update". Is that mean "IsCurrent" can also be used to check the remote device connecting state?

Comment: You generally detect remote desktops with ``GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION)``. Some remote scenarios will end up having the remote session connect to the "Microsoft Basic Renderer" you can detect via [VID/PID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#new-info-about-enumerating-adapters-for-windows-8)